# ignoring rows using :not() and styling with nth-of-type odd & even

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm wanting to style `li's` with alternative backgrounds. The pattern should go red > blue > red > blue etc.

The problem is I'm using a `:not` selector to ignore the first row in one list, and because of that the pattern for that list starts at blue > red > blue. I understand why that is but I'm wondering if it's possible to have the `:nth-of-type() odd and even` ignore the rows from it's calculations? Or if there is a work around without adding extra markup to my html.

http://jsbin.com/kusolecudo/edit?html,css,output

**I do not want to apply any extra markup to my HTML or duplicate my CSS  for the :not list.**

```css
li:not(.head):nth-of-type(odd)
{ background: red }

li:not(.head):nth-of-type(even)
{background: blue }


ul {width:40%;display:inline-block;list-style:none}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="head">
    test
  </li>
  <li>
    test
  </li>
  <li>
    test
  </li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li>
    test
  </li>
  <li>
    test
  </li>
  <li>
    test
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. It looks right to me?

Comment: Yes the first list item, but not all lists will contain 'that' row.

Comment: See the example. The list on the right is correct, the list on the left is incorrect because I want the red > blue alt rows to begin after the li.head row

Comment: I might be proven otherwise but I'm fairly confident that with the restrictions you put forth (no markup changes, no duplication of CSS), this is impossible. This would make this question un-answerable, so I suggest you modify it.

Comment: Seems quite unreasonable to me. Is there a reason why .head can't be a <h5> or something that's out of the ul altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there is no way to have the `:nth-of-type()` skip based on the result of `:not()` and basically pretend it's not there, you can achieve what seems to be your intention by adding three more definitions using [general siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) selectors.

CSS:

```
li:nth-of-type(odd)
{ background: red }

li:nth-of-type(even)
{background: blue }

li.head
{ background: none; }

li.head ~ li:nth-of-type(1n+2)
{ background:red; }

li.head ~ li:nth-of-type(2n+3)
{ background:blue; }

ul {width:40%;display:inline-block;list-style:none}
```

The `li.head ~ li` will select any `li`'s after the `.head` one and then you can apply the "odd"/"even" styling with an offset: `1n+2` and `2n+3`.

Here's a JSFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/rjschie/b538upum/

I hope that helps!

Comment: Good Job Ryan! You just beat me to it. I was just about to post almost the same thing! :)

Comment: Haha, thanks @LOTUSMS!